# Eclipse does not communicate (install) HelloWorld app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've this problem with Eclipse. When I debug my application, it gives me this info:

> [2011-07-16 13:39:50 - TestAndroidProject]
>
> [2011-07-16 13:39:50 - TestAndroidProject] Android Launch!
>
> [2011-07-16 13:39:50 - TestAndroidProject]
> adb is running normally.
> [2011-07-16 13:39:50 - TestAndroidProject] Performing nl.Diamondo25.TestAndroidProjectActivity activity launch
>
> [2011-07-16 13:39:50 - TestAndroidProject] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'derp_test' is not available. Launching new emulator.
>
> [2011-07-16 13:39:50 - TestAndroidProject] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'derp_test'
> [2011-07-16 13:40:47 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
> [2011-07-16 13:40:47 - Emulator]

The Emulator launches, but there is no app installed...

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: May be you need to wait for some time after the emulator launches. Do you see the command "installing .apk" in console?

Comment: Nope, I did not. I'm installing everything from the SDK tool now, maybe that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Delete all the emulators. Restart Eclipse. Create a new emulator and try again.

If the code is correct, all software, SDK, plugins etc. are available and Eclipse configured the correct way, I don't see why it shouldn't work